# How do I databind to a Winform control that is hosted in a WPF control?

Tags: wpf, winforms, data-binding, mvvm

I just thought about converting one of our custom controls to WPF, however it uses another custom control of ours that is written Winforms.

As there is little point in using WPF without MVVM.  How can I databind to a Winforms control that is used within a WPF control.

(I don’t have much WPF experience, so I may be missing the point completely)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't convert the inner-most winforms control to WPF? If so, please add this information to your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason, the app is many years old, the control works and is used by lots of other bits of UI that works.

Comment: I think Jonathan.Peppers has the right answer. Just host it in a WindowsFormsHost control and attach any dependency properties that are required for the UI to be able to interact with the functionality of the control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will have to wrap the WinForms control in a class exposing DependencyProperties or at least implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

So you'd have a class such as:

```
public class WinFormsWrapper : WindowsFormsHost
{
   //You'll have to setup the control as needed
   private static MyWinFormsControl _control;

   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSpinning", typeof(bool), typeof(WinFormsWrapper), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(_control.IsSpinning, new PropertyChangedCallback(IsSpinning_Changed)));

    private static void IsSpinning_Changed(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _control.IsSpinning = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }

    public bool IsSpinning
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Assuming that you have an IsSpinning property on your WinForms control.  Depending on your needs, it may be simpler to implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead of using DependencyProperties.

---

Added by Ian Ringrose:

This example code is clearly wrong (see comments about _control being static), but shows how to solve the problem.    As I am not using WPF at present, I am not going to edit the code as I can't test my edits.

I am keeping this answer as the accepted answer, as it contains the information needed to solve the problem.

I have added this to the answer, as comments do sometimes get deleted and this is getter views from people doing google searches.

Comment: Sorry but should _control declared as static? Would you give me a sample that using the wrapper class?

Comment: The sample above seems self-explanatory. You can just declare this in Xaml with `<local:WinFormsWrapper />`, if in code you could just create a new one and add it as a child of another control or window. I did change it to `static` so the example above builds, although it might be better to *not* be static when I look at this case. I answered this a really long time ago. I don't do much WPF these days.

Comment: WAKU, have you found any sample?